# jquery click container but exempt a wrapped element

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using jquery Isotope and have an element div that hold another div. These are tiles - of which there are many.

```
<div class=element > blah blah
<div class=setStamp>load X text</div>
blah blah blah blah
</div>
<div class=element > blah blah
<div class=setStamp>load Y text</div>
blah blah blah blah
</div>
```

There is a click trigger on all .element that toggles class 'large'
I want to be able to click setStamp and not trigger the toggle.
The best way I have so far is double click.

```
$container.delegate( '.element', 'dblclick', function(){ // enlarge clicked element
$(this).toggleClass('large');
$container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

But I would like to maintain a simple single click.
I am experimenting with ! .not() and generally looking.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is hard to follow. Could you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$container.on('click', '.element', function(){ // enlarge clicked element

   $(this).toggleClass('large');
   $container.isotope('reLayout');

}).on('click', '.setStamp', function( e ){

   e.stopPropagation();

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/UFOtovE/4/edit)

Or also like:

```
$container.on('click', '.element', function( e ){ // enlarge clicked element

   if(e.target.className=='setStamp') return;

   $(this).toggleClass('large');
   $container.isotope('reLayout');

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/UFOtovE/3/edit)

Comment: Hey Roko. THANKS..! Got it working. I had to use: $container.isotope('reLayout'); One approach I had used earlier was to add a .fake class and test: if hasClass then ignore. It took a while to see that this add was messing the className=='setStamp' test. I see you edited and presume the 2nd ver. was added? It looks a little more direct. And a big +1 for the example.

Comment: ?? There are actually 2 internal divs: setStamp & modal. Is there a way to include both in the same line? I have set: function( e, f ) then: if(f.target.className=='modal') { return; } It works but I wonder if there is some way of chaining or using || or?

Comment: doh! newbie - accept the answer. sure, but where be da buton man?

Comment: @Arfa in that case you need: `var cName= e.target.className; if(cName=='foo' || cName=='bar'){ /*do something*/ }` But rather use the first example.

Comment: @Arfa no, `function( e, f )` is wrong. `e` === `event` and we need that 'click' event.target

Comment: Gotcha. I will click that sucker 3 times (toggle :) And we need: var tar= e.target.className;

Comment: VERY good. I think we are done. I have a long way to go with js :)

Comment: @Arfa yeah, sometimes I wish we had that "plug" machine like Neo in *The Matrix* `:D`